# Getting a bad request 400 when trying to upload zipped wkt file to here-maps rest api

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, form-data, jszip, here-maps-rest

We have a problem with the fleet.ls.hereapi.com when uploading a new layer for geofencing.

```js
const myId = 'MYLAYER'; // just a id to check
zip.file('data.wkt', `NAME\tWKT\n${myId}\t${wkt}`);
const content = await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'nodebuffer' });
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('zipfile', content);
await axios.post(config.HERE_MAPS_UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, formData, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  params: {
    apiKey: config.HERE_MAPS_REST_API_KEY,
    layer_id: myId,
  },
});
```

We get a bad request without a message and do not know what the problem is. The same implementation works in the Frontend (with 'blob' as zip type). Is there a parameter to get a better error message from the api?
We got the instructions how to implement it from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ayw9GcS1V-8 and as I mentioned it works fine in the frontend. Also it works if I write a file in node and upload it via curl. Thank you for any help in advance!

> Edit: I'm getting the following issue from the API: 'Multipart should contain exactly one part but contains 0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! 
The problem was that the api needed a filename for the form data. This filename can be provided as third parameter as described [here](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#void-append-string-field-mixed-value--mixed-options-).

So I basically changed `formData.append('zipfile', content);` to `formData.append('zipfile', content, zipfile.zip);` and it worked.

Hope this will help somebody in the future!